# Magento2.3: How to move the custom block in account navigation sidebar?

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, phtml, sidebar, myaccount

I want to show the customer profile pic and the name after he/she logged in on the account navigation sidebar. I have successfully got those details. Please see below.

[image]

However, I want to show them above the My Account link. I have tried moving but not success.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Module::Test.phtml" before="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" cacheable="false" />
```

Comment: Can you please update your XML file's code where you have this profile pic block ?

Comment: <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
     <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Module::Test.phtml" cacheable="false" />
 </referenceContainer>

Comment: Above is my XML code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your XML with below content and check

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Module::Test.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false" />
```

Or

Add this line after referenceContainer tag

```
<move element="customer.session.data" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />
```

Or

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main.account_nav">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Module::Test.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kishan, it works great

Comment: You're welcome @Siva

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your block before `sidebar.main.account_nav` block, i.e your code in xml file-

```
 <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Module::Test.phtml" cacheable="false" before="sidebar.main.account_nav" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have tried but its not working. Checked with @Kishan answer and it works fine.